# Почему возникает такая ошибка при использовании foreach с объектом

Tags: php

вот код

```
foreach ($serId as $catS) {
   $idSer[]=  $catS->id_serial;}
var_dump( $idSer);
```

получаю такой массив

```
[0]=> int(5) [1]=> int(7) [2]=> int(13)
[3]=> int(14) [4]=> int(7) [5]=> int(60) [6]=> int(70) [7]=> int(77)
```

делаю так

```
foreach ($serId as $catS) {
    if($catS->id_serial) {
        $idSer['id'] = $catS->id_serial;
        $idSer['nesting'] = 'serial';
    }
 var_dump( $idSer);
```

получаю

```
array(2) { ["id"]=> int(17) ["nesting"]=> string(6) "serial" }
```

как мне получить id всех объектов в массив  с условием что id_serial не равно null

Comment: скобки не хватает во втором примере foreach, не?

Comment: Вы записываете в `$idSer['id']` значение, затем во втрой итерации цикла записываете сюда же заново стирая старое значение, попробуйте например так `$idSer[]['id']` и `$idSer[]['nesting']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, правильный код должен быть таким:

```
foreach ($serId as $catS) {
    if($catS->id_serial) {
        $idSer[] = [
            'id' => $catS->id_serial,
            'nesting' => 'serial'
        ];
    }
}
var_dump($idSer);
```

Comment: я получил такой массив  { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["nesting"]=> string(6) "serial" } [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(8) ["nesting"]=> string(6) "serial" } ...а мне надо все же вот так  {  ["id"]=> int(1) ["nesting"]=> string(6) "serial" ["id"]=> int(8) ["nesting"]=> string(6) "serial" ...

Comment: все вопрос исчерпан свою ошибку понял

Comment: @Sergalas если ответ верный - подтвердите это, пожалуйста. Если нет - расскажите, в чем моя ошибка и как будет верно.